# In Jena rules, how to select a literal according to the sorting of a specific property

Tags: jena, jena-rules

For instance, I got all cat instance by `(?c rdf:type eg:cat)` firstly. So, how to get the oldest cat according to the property `:has_age`?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with the `greaterThan` and `noValue` [primitives](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#RULEbuiltins), but this is obviously possible using SPARQL.